# Compress using 7zip with password protection in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, compression, 7zip

I have an encrypted file which I need to compress using 7zip with password protection. I couldn't find any useful reference online. I'm new to this zip file stuff and I don't have an idea if this approach is correct or not.

The code I have tried

```
public int zipSingleFile(String compressedDo1FilePath, File encryptedFile) throws IOException {
    try{
    SevenZOutputFile out = new SevenZOutputFile(encryptedFile);
      SevenZArchiveEntry entry = out.createArchiveEntry(encryptedFile, compressedDo1FilePath);
      out.putArchiveEntry(entry);
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
      byte[] b = new byte[1024];
      int count = 0;
      while ((count = in.read(b)) > 0) {
        out.write(b, 0, count);
      }
      out.closeArchiveEntry();
      return 0;
    } catch (IOException exception) {
      logger.info("exception occurred while zipping the file the file ={} ", exception);
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: you tried using the `SvenZOutputFile(File fileName, char[] password)` constructor?

Comment: @SquidXTV yeah did ... " cannot resolve constructor 'SevenZOutputFile(File, char[])"

Comment: Which libraries are you using? You didn't provide enough information for reproduction.

Comment: I'm using zip4j here

Comment: did you try these instructions from the front page of zip4j: https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j#creating-a-password-protected-zip-file--adding-files-to-an-existing-zip-with-password-protection

Comment: @jtahlborn couldnt find any 7zip related content

Comment: i'm confused, are you using zip4j or not?

Comment: I'm using zip4j and my requirement is to compress the file as a 7zip file with password

Answer (score 0):

Apache Compress can only read encrypted 7Zip file, you can't create one.

Ref : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/limitations.html

> Encryption, solid compression and header compression are only
> supported when reading archives

Comment: so we can't compress a file using 7zip with password protection ?

Comment: Oups, just realized that you are using zip4j not apache commons-compress. My answer was for Apache Commons.